# What does Bruce sing in the hallway?

Tags: soundtrack, filth

In *Filth* (2013), during the scene where Bruce and his partner interrogate the first subject (who sleeps with an uder-aged girl) James McAvoy sings, as he walks down the hallway, a song with a very familiar melody. Ever since I've first seen the movie I've been wondering what he actually sings. In the German translations he sings something like "child molester". For me it sounds like "stud-a-baas". Can anyone answer this for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He was chanting Stoat-the-baw, a Scottish slang phrase for Child Molester

http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199829941.001.0001/acref-9780199829941-e-45150

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=stoat-the-baw

In terms of the melody, its a very common football chant (eg. "England, England, England...").  I can find you the specific tune it's sung to if you need.